# How to search Library on Mavericks

Tags: macos, spotlight, search, library

Before updating to 10.9 I frequently deleted all the small files some apps leave behing by searching for invisible system files. Now it doesn't seem to work, I can navigate to the file manually just fine, but it doesn't show up in the search. Is there a way to index Library?

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching via command-f within Finder? If so, do you see a pair of dropdowns that say `Kind is Any`? Click `Kind` and select `System files`. `Any` will change to `aren't included`. Click it and change it to `are included`.

If `System files` isn't available in the first dropdown, select the last item, `Other…`, and find it in the subsequent popup.

If no dropdowns are shown, click the round `+` button on the right edge of the Finder window, near its top.

If you're searching via Menubar > Spotlight, I've looked in the past for a way to include hidden files in its search results, but to no avail.

Personally, I use [App Cleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), by the way, to tidy junk left by messy apps.

**ADDENDUM:**

I see now this works for most `Library` files, like those found in `Application Support` or `Internet Plug-ins`, but it fails specifically for `.plist` files found in the `Preferences` sub-folder. Not sure why Apple would do that.

Others have had this difficulty, too, and they've solved using App Cleaner or a similar third-party app:

http://lifehacker.com/5711409/how-to-search-for-hidden-packaged-and-system-files-in-os-x
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1599438
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20121101064200135

It seems the options are third-party app, manually search through Finder, or perhaps [`grep` through Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). Regardless, remember to leave http://www.apple.com/feedback/.

Comment: Yes, that's my search pattern. Like I said, I can navigate to the file manually just fine, so I KNOW it's there, but it doesn't come up while searching. I don't use cleaner apps, because after testing a bunch of them I always found that they leave stuff behind. Besides, they don't work if the app has been long gone, and now I'm just trying to delete the leftovers.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I've updated my answer above.